# Strict aliasing within an expression

Tags: c, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

Suppose we have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint16_t a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    const size_t n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(uint16_t);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        uint16_t *b = (uint16_t *) ((uint8_t *) a + i * sizeof(uint16_t));
        printf("%u\n", *b);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Clearly, casting `a` to an `uint8_t` pointer is not a violation, so this question is about casting that resulting pointer to an `uint16_t` pointer. In my understanding, according to the standard it does violate the strict aliasing rule. However, I am not sure from a practical point of view, since the types of `a` and `b` are compatible. The only potential violation is `b` aliasing the `uint8_t` pointer that exists only throughout this one expression. So in my understanding, even if it violates the rule, I would doubt that it can cause undefined behavior. Can it?

Note that I am not saying that this code is meaningful. The question is meant for purely educational purposes regarding the understanding of strict aliasing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **not** a strict aliasing violation.

The conversion of `a` to `uint8_t` and the subsequent pointer arithmetic is safe due to the exception given to a conversion to a pointer-to-character type.

Section 6.3.2.3p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type.  If the resulting  pointer  is  not  correctly  aligned68)for  the  referenced  type,  the  behavior  is undefined.   Otherwise, when  converted  back  again,  the  result  shall  compare  equal  to  theo riginal pointer.  **When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object.  Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.**

The conversion back and subsequent dereference is safe because `b` is pointing to an object of type `uint16_t` (specifically a member of the array `a`), matching the pointed-to type of `b`.

Section 6.5p7 states:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type  that  is  the  signed  or  unsigned  type  corresponding  to  the  effective  type  of  the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate  or  union  type  that  includes  one  of  the  aforementioned  types  among  its members (including, recursively, a
>   member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

Comment: No need for "pointer-to-character type" conversion - the `uint32_t a[]; b = (uint32_t*)((uint16_t*)a + i * sizeof(uint32_t)/sizeof(uint16_t))` would be also fine, right? The thing is, the resulting `uint16_t` pointer value is properly aligned to `uint16_t`.

Comment: @KamilCuk That's not strictly safe because you don't have an array of type `uint16_t` that you are allowed to do arithmetic on.  6.3.2.3p7 specifically allows for pointer arithmetic on a character type to access the object's representation.

Comment: @dbush What if it was `uint32_t` for `a` and `sizeof(uint32_t)` in both cases accordingly, but `b` remained `uint16_t` as it is? Maybe that better fits my intention of aliasing within an expression.

Comment: @Pedro That would be an aliasing violation upon dereference because you would be accessing a `uint32_t` as if it were a `uint16_t.

Comment: @dbush I think I can answer my own question: `b` wouldn't be compatible with `a` any more, so that would violate the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: _The conversion back ... is safe_ Could you add a link to the wording supporting this?